# Able to connect, despite no external IP / networks in Authorize Network?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm learning Cloud SQL and configured IP connectivity for a Cloud SQL instance, using this article: [Connecting mysql Client Using IP Addresses](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip)

However i'm a bit confused, even though no external network IP address listed in Authorize Networks Cloud SQL instance > AUTHORIZATION > Authorized networks (see screenshot)... I'm still able to connect to SQL instance and browse databases etc. I'm using both `$mysql` as well as `$gcloud sql connect` commands in local console / terminal (MacOS

fyi, if that helps, I had earlier whitelisted my IP but then deleted it from Authorized networks (could it be the deletion takes some time to reflect the change? I waited 30 min.!

Thanks for any clarificatin

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have been connecting the SQL instance using the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/) in your Google Cloud Platform project. Have you tried to access the SQL instance from another environment (Ex: [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine))?

Comment: @Digil I used gcloud SDK (local macOS Terminal)... it said temporarily whitelisting the IP... from the same machine (Terminal) connected via mySQL

Comment: On your [Cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#cloud-shell), seems like some sort of [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#iam_roles) active, which is superseding the authorized networks. The role could be  Cloud SQL Editor role, or some role with the cloudsql.instances.update permission, or even project owner. As I suggested in my previous have to tried to access this SQL instance from another environment?

Comment: I see.. thanks for the clarification! this starts to make sense :). cheers!